# select() message queue failed as bad address(EFAULT) on AIX 6.1.0.0

Tags: unix, select, ipc, message-queue, aix

On AIX 6.1.0.0, select() system call support for message queue, see http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_aix_61/com.ibm.aix.basetrf2/select.htm?lang=en

But the below code return failed with errno 14(EFAULT) after select() called:

```
int msgid = msgget(MQ_KEY, IPC_CREAT|06666);
if (-1 == msgid) {
    if (errno != EEXIST) {
        ETRACE("msgget() failed: key[%d], errno[%d]", MQ_KEY, errno);
        return -1;
    }

    msgid = msgget(MQ_KEY, 0);
    if (-1 == msgid) {
        ETRACE("msgget() failed: key[%d], errno[%d]", MQ_KEY, errno);
        return -1;
    }
}
DTRACE("msgget() success: msgid[%d]", msgid);

/* time out */
struct timeval to;
to.tv_sec = 10;
to.tv_usec = 0;

/* select list */
struct {
    int msgids[1];
} rlist, wlist, elist;

rlist.msgids[0] = msgid;
wlist.msgids[0] = msgid;
elist.msgids[0] = msgid;

/* number of list */
int nlist = 1 << 16;

/* int ret = select(nlist, (struct fd_set*)&rlist, (struct fd_set*)&wlist, (struct fd_set*)&elist, &to); */
int ret = select(nlist, (struct fd_set*)&rlist, NULL, NULL, &to);
if (0 == ret) {
    WTRACE("select() timeout: ret[%d]", ret);
}
else if (ret < 0) {
    ETRACE("select() failed: ret[%d], errno[%d]", ret, errno);
}
else {
    ITRACE("select() success");
}

return 0;
```

Comment: `int nlist = 1 << 16;` could be a bit too large. and ... `rlist.msgids[0] = msgid;` what is rlist?

Comment: In the manual of AIX 6.1.0.0 about the first argument `Nfdsmsgs` in select() said ***The low-order 16 bits give the length of a bit mask that specifies which file descriptors to check; the high-order 16 bits give the size of an array that contains message queue identifiers.*** And `rlist` is the struct stored msgid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Message queue support in `select()` and `poll()` is an AIX extension that is no longer enabled by default when compiling on AIX 5.3 and later versions.  To enable it, compile with `-D_MSGQSUPPORT` (or `#define _MSGQSUPPORT 1` before the first `#include`).

It is not mentioned on the `select()` manual page but the option is mentioned on the [`poll()` manual page](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_aix_61/com.ibm.aix.basetrf1/poll.htm?lang=en), and the same flag enables message queue support for both functions.